# what is the necessary steps of plugin customization

Tags: wordpress

I want to customize my plugin but I am beginner, so please  tell me what is the necessary steps for plugin customization either plugin is completed or simple.

Answer (score 1):

first you have to download the .zip file and unzip it. Then customize it like you need and make it to a .zip again. Then upload it on your Wordpress site.

Comment: can u tell me how to understand plugin code very easily, sometimes it is very complicated for me to understand plugin code, bcoz i have less knowlege of oops and mostly plugin are coded in oops language, so this is very complicated for me...plz help me krish

Answer (score 1):

If you already have that particular plugin(which you'd like to customize) installed on your wordpress, you may find the source code files under the following path:

```
[your_wordpress_dir]/wp-content/plugins/
```

If you want to customize a plugin that is available for download, you may follow the below steps

1. download it from [wp_download_manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/)
2. unzip the package and find the source files where you can customize it.
3. put the customized plugin package in the above mentioned path in your wordpress directory(if you'd like to have this plugin installed in your wordpress project).

If you want your plugin to be available for public, you may add it to [wp directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add/)